# Optimizing an AVG / GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, group-by

Here is the query:

```
SELECT p.domain_id AS comp, AVG(IFNULL(p.position, 50)) as AVG, p.date AS period
    FROM userdomain ud
    LEFT JOIN userdomainexpression ude
        ON ude.userdomain_id=ud.id
    LEFT JOIN expression e
        ON e.id=ude.expression_id
    LEFT JOIN request r
        ON r.expression_id=e.id
    LEFT JOIN position p
        ON p.request_id=r.id
    WHERE ud.id=4
        AND p.domain_id IN (3,8,13,67,6,5,15,17,7,10,9,12,16,1,2,4,11,14)
        AND p.date >= '2014-11-01' AND p.date <= '2015-03-23'
    GROUP BY period, p.domain_id
```

At the moment it takes about 20 seconds to process. position has about 6 millions rows. Others less than a few thousands.

Here is the EXPLAIN:

```
id? select_type?    table?  partitions? type?   possible_keys?  key?    key_len?    ref?    rows?   Extra?
1   SIMPLE  ud  NULL    const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  ude NULL    ref userdomain_id_expression_id,userdomain_id,expression_id userdomain_id_expression_id 5   const   1202    Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  e   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   hugemetrics_prod.ude.expression_id  1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  r   NULL    ref PRIMARY,expression_id   expression_id   5   hugemetrics_prod.e.id   1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  p   NULL    ref request_id_domain_id_date,request_id,domain_id,date request_id_domain_id_date   5   hugemetrics_prod.r.id   462 Using where
```

When I remove the select AVG, it drops to 3/4 seconds (which is much better but still not great).

EXPLAIN tells me it uses another index for the last line:

```
id? select_type?    table?  partitions? type?   possible_keys?  key?    key_len?    ref?    rows?   Extra?
1   SIMPLE  ud  NULL    const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  ude NULL    ref userdomain_id_expression_id,userdomain_id,expression_id userdomain_id_expression_id 5   const   1202    Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  e   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   hugemetrics_prod.ude.expression_id  1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  r   NULL    ref PRIMARY,expression_id   expression_id   5   hugemetrics_prod.e.id   1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  p   NULL    ref request_id_domain_id_date,request_id,domain_id,date request_id_domain_id_date   5   hugemetrics_prod.r.id   462 Using where; Using index
```

I have indexes on ud.id, e.id, ude.expression_id, r.expression_id, e.id, p.position, p.request_id, r.id, p.domain and p.date.

I'm not sure why avg() prevents the use of index and increases so much the duration, and how to optimize the query to reach <1sec?

---

As ypercube suggested, the query is now:

```
SELECT 
      p.domain_id AS comp, 
      AVG(IFNULL(p.position, 50)) AS avg, 
      p.date AS period
FROM 
      userdomainexpression AS ude
    JOIN request r
        ON r.expression_id = ude.expression_id
    JOIN position p
        ON p.request_id = r.id
WHERE 
      ude.userdomain_id = 4
  AND p.domain_id IN (3,8,13,67,6,5,15,17,7,10,9,12,16,1,2,4,11,14)
  AND p.date >= '2014-11-01' AND p.date <= '2015-03-23'
GROUP BY 
      p.date, p.domain_id ;
```

I think the timing is a bit better but still very slow anyway.

The EXPLAIN:

```
id? select_type?    table?  partitions? type?   possible_keys?  key?    key_len?    ref?    rows?   Extra?
1   SIMPLE  ude NULL    ref userdomain_id_expression_id,userdomain_id,expression_id userdomain_id_expression_id 5   const   1202    Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  r   NULL    ref PRIMARY,expression_id   expression_id   5   hugemetrics_test.ude.expression_id  1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  p   NULL    ref request_id_domain_id_date,request_id,domain_id,date,date_domain_id_position request_id_domain_id_date   5   hugemetrics_test.r.id   977 Using where
```

And create table queries:

```
-- Adminer 4.1.0 MySQL dump

SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `position`;
CREATE TABLE `position` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oneboxPosition` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serp_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serp_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `request_id_domain_id_date` (`request_id`,`domain_id`,`date`),
  KEY `request_id` (`request_id`),
  KEY `domain_id` (`domain_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `serp_type` (`serp_type`),
  KEY `serp_id` (`serp_id`),
  KEY `oneboxPosition` (`oneboxPosition`),
  KEY `position` (`position`),
  KEY `date_domain_id_position` (`date`,`domain_id`,`position`),
  CONSTRAINT `position_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`request_id`) REFERENCES `request` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `request`;
CREATE TABLE `request` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `engine` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datacenter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `engine_region_language_expression_id` (`engine`,`region`,`language`,`expression_id`),
  KEY `expression_id` (`expression_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `userdomainexpression`;
CREATE TABLE `userdomainexpression` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `userdomain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userdomain_id_expression_id` (`userdomain_id`,`expression_id`),
  KEY `userdomain_id` (`userdomain_id`),
  KEY `expression_id` (`expression_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- 2015-03-24 12:40:26
```

Comment: A composite index on `(date, domain_id)` would probably help better than the 2 indexes.

Comment: Right. Seems like it helps a bit, but still at least >=15sec.

Comment: Is there a unique constraint on `userdomainexpression (userdomain_id, expression_id)`?

Comment: Yes. Can it slow down the query? How?

Comment: Can you show us the explain for the query in my answer? (It would also help to have all the `CREATE TABLE` scripts.)

Comment: Ah, sorry. The index should include the `position` as well. Most probbaly the best would be on `(date, domain_id, position)`.

Comment: (the unique constraint by the way is fine, it won't slow the query. On the contrary, it might be helpful.)

Comment: I have added what you asked for in the question post.

Comment: I will try to experiment with some other possible indexes - like `(date, domain_id, request_id, position)` - and rewrites but it'll take some time to write scripts so I have real sized tables. I'll be back to you.

Answer (score 1):

- A composite index on `position (date, domain_id, position)` and on `userdomainexpression (userdomain_id, expression_id)` would help I think.
- The join to `userdomain` is not needed.
- Assuming foreign keys exist, the join to `expression` could be removed as well.
- The `LEFT` joins are actually (equivalent to) `INNER` joins (due to the `WHERE` conditions.
- You could try to rewrite, using `GROUP BY` only in `positions` and then join (It might be better or worse, worth a try).
- Other possible rewrites, using `EXISTS` or a subquery (with `DISTINCT`) for the join to `userdomainexpression`. This might be useful if there is no unique constraint on `userdomainexpression (userdomain_id, expression_id)`.

A suggestion, removing 2 tables from the joins:

```
SELECT 
      p.domain_id AS comp, 
      AVG(IFNULL(p.position, 50)) AS avg, 
      p.date AS period
FROM 
      userdomainexpression AS ude
    JOIN request r
        ON r.expression_id = ude.expression_id
    JOIN position p
        ON p.request_id = r.id
WHERE 
      ude.userdomain_id = 4
  AND p.domain_id IN (3,8,13,67,6,5,15,17,7,10,9,12,16,1,2,4,11,14)
  AND p.date >= '2014-11-01' AND p.date <= '2015-03-23'
GROUP BY 
      p.date, p.domain_id ;
```

Comment: @leyou I really would like to see the results of ypecube's analysis. Great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The indexes on `userdomainexpression` can be simplified:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userdomain_id_expression_id` (`userdomain_id`,`expression_id`),
  KEY `userdomain_id` (`userdomain_id`),
  KEY `expression_id` (`expression_id`)
```

-->

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`userdomain_id`, `expression_id`),
  KEY         (`expression_id`, `userdomain_id`)
```

And that will speed up queries that need to go from Expression to UserDomain.

In `position`, these are redundant and can be DROPped:

```
KEY `request_id` (`request_id`),
KEY `date` (`date`),
```

You are JOINing on NULLable fields.  Can those fields ever be NULL?  If not, consider adding 'NOT NULL' to the column definitions wherever appropriate.

Because of the JOINs, I suspect the aggregate (AVG) is incorrectly computed.  To prove (or disprove) this, run the query without the `GROUP BY` and "AVG" (but keep p.position) and see if there are duplicate p.position values.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However it didn't improve the speed much. Without GROUP BY it just returns a single row. Here is a pastebin with the create table scripts: http://pastebin.com/6qZ8ZtcG

Comment: By the way, just by removing the AVG it goes down from around 20sec to 4sec. Not sure why. And also, I have added the explain in the pastebin,

Comment: Oops, When I said to remove the `GROUP BY`, I should have said to change `AVG(IFNULL(p.position, 50)) as AVG` to `IFNULL(p.position, 50)`.

Comment: 1202*4*589 (2.8M) is a large number.  That product is the estimate of the number of rows needed to compute the query.  (The numbers came from the EXPLAIN.)  To construct 2.8M rows, then perform a GROUP BY will take a lot of time.  "Using index" says that the indexes are as good as possible.

Comment: If the SELECT I suggested you do comes back with 2.8M rows, I am worried that the arithmetic will be wrong.  Fixing that should be the first priority.  Although it _seems_ to involve only `position`, there is the annoying `ude.userdomain_id = 4` that I don't see how to fold into without fetching 2.8M rows.

Comment: It does come back with 2.8M rows. I'm not sure there is a better solution here to compute the AVG of those 2.8M rows on the fly. I probably need to precompute and store the average for each day and domain.

Comment: Bingo.  Build a "Summary Table", populate it each day with `COUNT(*)` and `SUM(...)`.  Then build the 'report' from that table, using (sum of sums) / sum of counts) as the overall average.  [My blog on such](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)